# Detecting Focus on (frame + components) in swing

Tags: java, swing, focus

I have a small dialog frame that appears, and within this frame are a series of buttons and a textbox. 
I need the frame to be able to detect when the user has put focus on something else on the screen (being: anything besides the frame and its components), so I can close down the frame.
Any advice on how to go about this? I've been trying at focus solutions for hours, to no solution!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> need the frame to be able to detect when the user has put focus on something else on the screen

Use a WindowListener and listen for windowDeactivated.

Answer (score 5):

Try using a [WindowStateListener](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/awt/event/WindowStateListener.html)

The WindowEvent parameter it provides can tell you if the window has lost focus through the getNewState() method.

```
class MyFocusLostListener implements WindowStateListener {

    public void windowStateChanged(WindowEvent e) {
        if (e.getNewState() == WindowEvent.WINDOW_LOST_FOCUS) {
            e.getWindow().setVisible(false);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

listen to property changes of the property "permanentFocusOwner" of the KeyboardFocusManager. On being notified, check if the new focusOwner is in the child hierarchy under the frame, if not - close the frame.

Edit: seeing the answers suggesting a Window/StateListener - they are better than mine for a top-level window :-) Listening to the keyboardFocusManager is a good approach for containers deeper down in the hierarchy, implemented f.i. in the CellEditorRemover of a JTable (to decide if a pending edit should be terminated)