# Automatically close a JFrame window when clicking outside it

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I have a fairly basic JFrame here, and I want to make the window close automatically when the user clicks outside it. Is it possible to make the window close when the user clicks outside it (by somehow detecting clicks outside the window?).

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ExampleJFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("How can I make this window close when I click outside it?");
        frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        JLabel jlbempty = new JLabel("");
        jlbempty.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 200));
        frame.getContentPane().add(jlbempty, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: I hope this is relevant to my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5717716/detecting-focus-on-frame-components-in-swing

Comment: Actually that question contains the exact answer that you need...

Comment: this won't work in all situations, but you could close the frame once it has lost focus.

Comment: Once you detect the lost focus, closing the window is easy.

Comment: *Automatically close a JFrame window when clicking outside it* May I ask why? this is not a very user friendly design

Comment: @DavidKroukamp I'm trying to create a right-click context menu that automatically closes when the user clicks outside the context menu - that is how context menus are supposed to behave. I plan to use this context menu in another application that is written using node-webkit.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Detecting a click outside the frame is difficult, as it can be a click on any other application to which java has no access.

You could try with a `FocusListener` as shown below

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;
import java.awt.event.FocusEvent;
import java.awt.event.FocusListener;

public class AutoCloseFrameDemo {
  public static void main( String[] args ) {
    final JFrame frame = new JFrame( "Test" );
    frame.addFocusListener( new FocusListener() {
      private boolean gained = false;
      @Override
      public void focusGained( FocusEvent e ) {
        gained = true;
      }

      @Override
      public void focusLost( FocusEvent e ) {
        if ( gained ){
          frame.dispose();
        }
      }
    } );
    frame.add( new JLabel( "testlabel" ) );

    frame.pack();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
    frame.setVisible( true );
  }
}
```

This works for this simple use-case. Not yet sure what will happen if you put e.g. a `JTextField` in the frame and the textfield gets focus. If that causes the `JFrame` to loose focus as well, your application will rather be useless.

**Edit**

A bit more robust solution might be to attach a listener to the `KeyboardFocusManager`

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyVetoException;
import java.beans.VetoableChangeListener;

public class AutoCloseFrameDemo {
  public static void main( String[] args ) {
    final JFrame frame = new JFrame( "Test" );

    KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager().
        addVetoableChangeListener( "focusedWindow",
                                   new VetoableChangeListener() {
                                     private boolean gained = false;

                                     @Override
                                     public void vetoableChange( PropertyChangeEvent evt ) throws PropertyVetoException {
                                       if ( evt.getNewValue() == frame ) {
                                         gained = true;
                                       }
                                       if ( gained && evt.getNewValue() != frame ) {
                                         frame.dispose();
                                       }
                                     }
                                   } );

    frame.add( new JTextField( 10 ), BorderLayout.NORTH );
    frame.add( new JTextField( 10 ), BorderLayout.SOUTH );

    frame.pack();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
    frame.setVisible( true );
  }
}
```

This allows to switch focus between the different text fields in the frame.

Comment: You could use WindowListener#windowDeactivated or WindowFocusListener#windowLostFocus

Comment: @MadProgrammer Yeah I second that but you have to be careful with owned JDialog's (as you have to be with FocusListener anyway).